# WPF application shows managed has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d) in InitializeComponent call

Tags: wpf, interop, .net-assembly

When I launch my WPF application and when it goes to `InitializeComponent` function call of one user control, it silently quits and only leaves one message in the output window saying Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code `-1073740771` (`0xc000041d`). When I say "silently", I mean there is no exception is caught even if I wrap this `InitializeComponent` call with a `try`-`catch` block (that's how I normally find where the problem is)

Here is what I did: in this application project we need to use a reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc.dll, with version number 10.0.4504.0. Since it is an interop library, when I added this reference in VS2012, it automatically sets the property `Embedded Interop Types` as true, which I assume means it will not keep an individual dll in the output folder but instead embed this library into the main output (at least this is how it seems in our other references, for example, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll). However, when I launch the project, it throws an `XamlParseException` saying:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc, Version=10.0.4504.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc, Version=10.0.4504.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35""

It seems that the reference was not embedded(or the version is not currect. But I verified that the reference version is indeed 10.0.4504.0)

Next I copied this dll directly to the output folder `bin\Debug\`, to make sure that it can find this library. This time the exception is not thrown, but the whole application just silently quits as I described in the beginning. I tried to google the code `-1073740771` (`0xc000041d`) but there is no article about it. I tried to set the `Embedded Interop Types` to true/false but the problem is the same.

UPDATE:

I'd like to add more description here. As mentioned above, the problematic library is OWC(Office Web Component)10. I followed this link to make OWC work with VB.NET desktop application: [HOW TO: Handle Events for the Office Web Components in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328275/EN-US). But this official article is so old so I had to make a lot of changes to compile the wrapper dll(mainly because of namespace mismatch). Then when I add the reference to the actual interop library Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc, if I follow the default setting and let the Embedded Interop Types as True, at runtime it will complain (throw a `XamlParseException`) that the assembly cannot be loaded (see description above). What the hell? I thought make it as "embedded" would guarantee this library will be found. Then I copy this dll to the output folder, then I have this silently quit problem. But it might be worth mentioning that this time the output window shows the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc.dll` is indeed loaded. Actually it is the last message before the `managed has exited` message. So it must still relate to this library.

All of this only happens with OWC10. There is actually a similar way to do that in OWC11(the latest, but unfortunately still pretty old version since it came with Office2003): [HOW TO: Handle Events for the Office 2003 Web Components in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823982). But it actually works and the control is displayed on my application. It is because of some other reason that I wanted to try OWC10 instead of OWC11

Comment: Try to turn on all Exceptions.

Comment: @Tomtom I turned all exceptions already(I enabled everything under user-unhandled). Plus, like I mentioned, I put the InitializeComponent call directly with a try-catch block and set a breakpoint in the catch, doesn't it guarantee the exception(if there is one, I am not sure) will be caught?

Comment: This is a pretty obscure low-level operating system exception.  I'll guess that you run on the 64-bit version of Windows, either Vista or Win7, have the Platform target set to x86 and see a "First chance" exception notification in the Output window.  If that's a match then add those details to your question.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply. Your description is almost right except that I don't even get any first chance exception in the output window. Other than that, I am indeed using a 64 bit Windows8 dev machine, and the target is x86. I have some more description in the update to the original post

Comment: Nothing I was thinking of.  You are using a big chunk of really old unmanaged code on a really new operating system.  Bad combination.  The exit code is too obscure to formulate a good theory, you'll need help from Microsoft Support to chase this down.  Updating to a more recent Office version would likely be their advice though.

Comment: @HansPassant as I mentioned, OWC11 which came with OFFICE2003 is the latest version. The reason we want to try it is because WPF is still lacking a lot of functionality in reporting. We tried report viewer from Windows Forms, but it, as well as OWC, is not handy in report application especially in printing. But thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> When I launch my WPF application and when it goes to InitializeComponent function call of one user >control, it silently quits and only leaves one message in the output window saying Managed 
>   (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d). When I say "silently", I mean there is >no exception is caught even if I wrap this InitializeComponent call with a try-catch block (that's >how I normally find where the problem is)
>
> Next I copied this dll directly to the output folder bin\Debug\, to make sure that it can find this >library. This time the exception is not thrown, but the whole application just silently quits as I >described in the beginning. I tried to google the code -1073740771 (0xc000041d) but there is no >article about it. I tried to set the Embedded Interop Types to true/false but the problem is the >same.

I had exactly the same thing happening to me today,  "has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d)." (This happened in both a VB and C# .NET WinForms application for me). I tried debugging and saw I never even got into the Form_Load code block.

I "solved" this in the end by running visual studio as an administrator (and then just opening & building and running the project via the menu).
This is a win8 security issue and it isn't well explained anywhere.
(I got distracted and just opened up a specific project straight out of my task bar/solution file which caused this to happen to me).

You've probably found this out by yourself by now, hope you didn't lose any hair over it :)
Just pointing this out for other people who might have this error occuring somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue, the 'silent' exit with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d) on x64 platforms, on x86 platforms everything was OK.

Part of my application is unmanaged C++, another part is C#. It turned out that my C++ code was not completely ready for the x64 platform. The following change fixed the issue in my case:

```
// before
g_OrigWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(::SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC,
                reinterpret_cast<LONG>(WindowProc)));

// fixed version
g_OrigWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(::SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC,
                reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(WindowProc)));
```

So, the generic recommendation is to verify that your code is completely ready for the x64 platform.